# Using various Eclipse ini files

Tags: eclipse, configuration, environment-variables, command-line-arguments

I am using a software client based on Eclipse (Ganymede) and its all working fine.
However, one small thing would make my world perfect...

In the Eclipse home folder, there is an ini-file. Is there a way to have various ini-files and choose (for example by arguments or environment variables) a specific ini file and create a shortcut for it?

Many thanks,

Comment: Because it would make my world perfect.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can make as many shortcut you want with the:

- the `eclipse.exe` executable
- the option `--launcher.ini /your/eclipse.ini`

See [Eclipse Help page on Runtime Options](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html):

```
--launcher.ini <location> (Executable)
```

> The location of the product `.ini` file to use.
> If not specified the executable will look for a file beside the launcher with the same name and the extension `.ini`.
> (ie `eclipse.exe` looks for `eclipse.ini`, `product.exe` looks for `product.ini`)

So you can have more than one "`eclipse.ini`" file: each one will be referenced as an argument within the `--launcher.ini` option.

Comment: Seriously, I love you! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: is it a typo or both `-launcher.ini` and `--launcher.ini` work ?

Comment: @Sybuser It was a typo indeed (12 years earlier). I have edited the answer.

Comment: Is --launcher.ini specific to Eclipse, or I can use this to run any software .exe with specified .ini file?

Comment: @RahulVala it is specific to Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to have a shell script (for *nix) or batch file for windows that would simulate the behaviour you want

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo "first arg is the name of the ini file to use otherwise using default one"

ln -s $1 eclipse.ini

#launch eclipse
```